# Is it possible to modify video stream by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

For my goals I'm using html5 and tag < video> to add a media content to page. I've found how to control video by JavaScript(stop, play, load). But is there any ways to modify processing video stream.

I'm trying to find a solutions how to add my sequence of bytes into downloaded stream: e.g modify header of file before playing.

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious what you try to achieve. But in general, HTML5 video does not support client-side dynamically generated video streams.

Answer (score 4):

There's no API for modifying the video stream bytes in the `video` element.

You can:

- Draw the current frame of the `video` element on `canvas`
- Apply an SVG filter to the `video` element (in Gecko)
- Use vendor-specific `XMLHttpRequest` extensions to read the bytes of the video file in JavaScript, modify the data, construct a `data:` URL from the data and load the `data:` URL into the `video` element.

Answer (score 0):

A `<video>` element can be manipulated visually similarly to a `<canvas>` element.  Take a look at this article at the Mozilla Hacks blog for a few good examples of what you can do with HTML5 video: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/pop-art-video/

But as far as modifying the actual video data stream, there isn't really a way to do that on the client side.

Comment: To be precise, you can manipulate the video after drawing it to a canvas. This is very slow though and only useful for demos.

Comment: Chrome are trying out GPU acceleration on 2D canvas contexts, and I'm sure FF will follow.